# When I press enter on an EditText, the focus goes to the next EditText view. How can i stop that from happening?

Tags: android

I have more than one EditText view in the same layout.  So what I want is that once the enter/done is pressed the next EditText view shouldn't become focused, unless of course I click on it?

Comment: in Enter/Done clear focus of all the field by using  `.clearFocus();`

Comment: @MD You are right . I faced this problem

Comment: @pleo926 Review my answer .

Answer (score 1):

Just use  **`EditText.clearFocus() Method`** .

For more details you can visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearFocus()